# Visual Studio Test Explorer result can not get replicated

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

```
 [TestClass]
public class FileTransferTestMethods
{
    Result objFTResult = new Result();
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    #region INCOMMING Test Scenarios
    /*Logging Mechanism: This includes logging of error and sending email as configured using NLog*/
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("File Transfer")]
    public void TCF01_FileTran_Inc_UT_RunningJob()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Starting File Incoming Job");
            FileTransfer.FileTransferIncomingJob.FileIncomingRun();
            _logger.Info("Completion of File Incoming Job");
            objFTResult.PassMsg("FT Incomming(TCF01)", "", "Pass", "FT Incomming Job Completed Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objFTResult.FailMsg("FT Incoming(TCF01)", "", "Fail", ex.Message);
            _logger.Info("File Incoming Job failed with exceptions");
        }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("File Transfer")]
    public void TCF02_FileTran_Inc_FT_DirectJobCall()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Starting File Incoming Job");

            FileTransferService.FileTransferServiceManagerClient t2=new FileTransferService.FileTransferServiceManagerClient();
            t2.RunIncomingFileJob();

            _logger.Info("Completion of File Incoming Job");
            objFTResult.PassMsg("FT Incomming(TCF02)", "", "Pass", "FT Incomming Job Completed Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objFTResult.FailMsg("FT Incoming(TCF02)", "", "Fail", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

When i tried to execute test methods from "Test Explorer" in VS, i am getting result file generated successfully, but when i tried to call test methods from a UI, i am not getting same result generated.